# Constructor chaining in Java, when is super called?

Tags: java, constructor, constructor-chaining

If you have a constructor which calls this() when is super() called? In the first constructor called? Or in the last constructor without the keyword this()?

Main calls: new B()

```
public class A {
    public A(){
       System.out.print("A ");
    }
}
public class B extends A {
 public B(){
       // is super called here? Option 1
       this(1);
       System.out.print("B0 ");
    }
 public B(int i){
       // or is super called here? Option 2
       System.out.print("B1 ");
    }
}
```

In this example the Output is: "A B1 B0". But it isn't clear to me, if the super() constructor is called at Option 1 or Option 2 (because the Output would be the same, in this case).

Comment: `B()` calls `B(int)` (using `this(1)`), so it doesn't call super. `B(int)` doesn't have an explicit constructor invocation, so the compiler generates a call to `super()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can deduce the answer by following this simple rule:

> Only one super constructor will be called, and it will only be called once.

So, the super constructor could not possibly be invoked from `B()` because it would be invoked again from `B(int)`.

Specifically, in the Java Language Specification (JLS) section [8.8.7. "Constructor Body"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7) we read:

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "super();", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.

In other words, if the constructor body ***does*** begin with an explicit constructor invocation, then there will be ***no*** implicit superclass constructor invocation.

(When the JLS speaks of a constructor body beginning with "an explicit constructor invocation" it means an invocation of another constructor *of the same class*.)

Answer (score 0):

When instantiating a new object, using `new B()`, it automatically calls the no-arguments constructor. In your case, `public B()`.

**In the no-arguments constructor:**
Because your constructor specified either a call to another constructor (using `this()`) or a manually specified call to the superclass constructor (using `super()`), there is no other call to another constructor. If your constructor was to only have the printing line (`System.out.print("B0);`), `super()` would have been automatically called. Now, you're calling `this(1)`, so your first constructor won't output anything **yet**, but will go to your second constructor, having an `int` argument.

**In the second constructor (with int argument):**
As I specified already, if your constructor doesn't have an explicit call to `this()` or `super()`, it automatically calls `super()` (*without any arguments unless manually specified*). Because `super()` must **always** be the first call in a constructor, it is executed before your `print`, meaning that `A()` is called. The first thing to be printed would be `A`. Moving on, there will be `B1` printed.

**Back in your first constructor (no args):**
`this(1)` has already been called, so it moves to the next statement, the one that prints something. So `B0` will be printed.

Now, as a recap, for a proper answer: `super()` is automatically called only in `public B(int i)`, because you already specified a call to `this()` in your first constructor, and `super()` is only called automatically when you don't specify `this()` or an explicit call to `super()`.